# How to redirect to multiple websites with a delay, by using the setTimeout function?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I want to be able to redirect to multiple websites, one after another with a bit of a delay, but don't know how to do it. I tried to use the setTimeout function, but it didn't work. Here's the code, I know that's something is obviously wrong, but don't have a clue what's wrong.

Here's a script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  redirectTime = "5000";
  redirectURL = "http://www.add-example.com";

  function timedRedirect(window.location) {
    setTimeout("location.href = redirectURL;", redirectTime);
    if (window.location = "http://www.add-example.com") {
      setTimeout("location.href = 'https://www.google.com';", 5000);
    }
</script>

<form name="login" action="$(link-login-only)" method="post" $(if chap-id) onSubmit="return doLogin()" $(endif)><input type="hidden" name="dst" value="http://www.add-example.com" />
  <input type="hidden" name="popup" value="true" />
  <table width="100%" class="maintab">
    <tr>
      <td align="right" /></td>
      <td><input class="username" name="username" type="text" value="$(username)" maxlength="10" /> </td><br />
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp; </td>
      <td align="left"><input class="submit" type="submit" name="ok" value="OK" OnClick="JavaScript:timedRedirect(window.location);" />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: You can't do this. Once `window.location.href === 'https://www.google.com'` your script is no longer running. You'd have to do this in an iframe, and hope all of the sites allow being viewed in frames.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
const urls = [
  'https://stackoverflow.com/',
  'https://math.stackexchange.com/',
  'https://codereview.stackexchange.com/',
  'https://cs.stackexchange.com/'
];

for (let i = 0; i < urls.length; i++) {
  setTimeout(() => {
    const a = document.createElement('a');

    a.style.display = 'none';
    a.href = urls[i];
    a.target = '_blank';
    document.body.appendChild(a);

    a.click();
    a.remove();
  }, i * 2000);
}
```

Comment: There is no reason to assign `a` an `id`. You currently do this to be able to execute `document.getElementById(id)`, however you might as well use `a.click()` and `a.remove()` since you already have the `a` variable. `document.getElementById(id) == a` should return `true`.

Comment: Thx! I'll try this out

Comment: Here's the edited code with iframe, the issue with it is that when you try to go through the authorization process by tapping on a wifi authorization pop up on Android, and authorize by entering the phone number and pressing a button, it shows the authorization page in Iframe, but If you try to go through authorization process through a third party brother like Chrome by inputting a phone number and pressing the Ok button, it shows an advertisement site in an Iframe, but doesn't redirect to the tab that's been visited before by user, and is stored in browsers cache.